# PFSense on Hyper-V - Can't Access VMs from hypervisor

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, pfsense

I'm hoping someone can help clarify what i'm doing, perhaps i'm missing something obvious, but I'm trying to setup PFSense as a VM on my workstation.

I've ceated two virtual switches, one external (linked to my NIC for WAN connection) the other as an internal switch (I've tried private too)

[image: pfsense interface config]

I've made two VLANs (105,110) and have assigned a static IP to its interfaces. I'm able to reach all three IPs from the PFsense, and from a test server sitting in VLAN 105.

[image: linux VM]

It appears everything from within the lab network works well, as from the VM (in the picture above) i can access all internal and external networks from it (including public internet)

What confuses me, is I'm unable to reach anything from my workstation (the Hypervisor) in any of these networks (10.0.0.0/24 and 10.0.10.0/24) other than the PFSense firewall since it has the external network of course.

I have the PFSense network adapters in HyperV configured as trunk ports allowing the respective VLANs (via Set-VMNetworkAdapterVlan) but I still can't access anything. Am I missing something obvious here?

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

--Update

Another odd thing, is it appears the connection is intermitted, and I'm not exactly sure why lol.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring out my problem. I had a vpn client (Forcepoint to be exact) I noticed every time I'd try to ping that IP, the forcepoint client would prompt me to login. I suspect it's looking for traffic outside my network, and if it think's i need to VPN in, it's prompting me to login..

Anyways, I had already created and deleted my static route a million times, but I also noticed I had a loop when running traceroute. It just kept hopping to my router (192.168.1.1) endlessly. I uninstalled forcepoint client and everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried several times to set up pfSense under Hyper-V and always had the same problem that communication with pfSense was interrupted after first reboot.
So far, I've always switched back to Virtualbox, but now that I need it for work on Hyper-V, I searched harder for the cause and found it:

*When setting up switches for Hyper-V, it seems they are always defined as "public", which prevents communication with pfSense on the LAN interface with private IP ranges.*

In addition, there is the problem with Windows 10 Pro 21H1 installations (at work with domain as well as privately with home network) that the GUI switch is no longer displayed.
After a long search I was able to find a Powershell solution for this, among others here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/73866/how-to-change-network-settings-from-public-to-priv.html

> 1. Get-NetConnectionProfile and press Enter. Information is then shown about the active network connection.
> 2. Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name "NetworkName" -NetworkCategory Private. Replace NetworkName with the value of the Name field shared
>    by the previous command.
>    To double check that the network location was changed, run the Get-NetConnectionProfile again and see the results. The
>    NetworkCategory field should have a different value.